# What is the difference between /proc/self/stack and output from pstack?

Tags: kernel, monitoring, debugging, proc, linux-kernel

I have been looking through the documentation for /proc and the "stack" object being a new'ish object in proc, I have also looked through the kernel commit to create it -- however the documentation does not detail exactly what is in the /proc/self/stack file -- and since I intuitively expected it to be the actual stack of the process -- however the old `pstack` tool gives a different (and more believable) output.

So as an example of the stack for bash

```
$ cat /proc/self/stack 
[<ffffffff8106f955>] do_wait+0x1c5/0x250
[<ffffffff8106fa83>] sys_wait4+0xa3/0x100
[<ffffffff81013172>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

and, using pstack

```
$ pstack $$
#0  0x00000038cfaa664e in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000043ed42 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000043ffbf in wait_for ()
#3  0x0000000000430bc9 in execute_command_internal ()
#4  0x0000000000430dbe in execute_command ()
#5  0x000000000041d526 in reader_loop ()
#6  0x000000000041ccde in main ()
```

The addresses are different, and obviously the symbols are not at all the same....

Does anybody have an explanation for the difference and/or a document which describes what is actually shown in /proc-stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file `/proc/$pid/stacks` shows kernel stacks. On your system, memory addresses of the form ffffffff8xxxxxxx are in the space that's reserved for the kernel. There's not much documentation, you can check the [source code](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/+code=proc_pid_stack). In contracst, the `pstack` program shows user-space stacks (using its knowledge of executable formats).

Comment: That was what I was guessing as well -- however I could not find any documentation on that.